# "Embalagens de salgadinho são laminadas" or "Embalagens de salgadinho são laminada."

Tags: gramática

Okay guys, another quick doubt. I have been trying to research this one out but was unable to. In the text below:

> Vamos falar de embalagens de salgadinho. Embalagens de salgadinho por exemplo, elas são laminadas. Geralmente quando você vai abrir elas rasgam, derramam tudo, é uma tristeza! As de batata é a mesma coisa. A do café também! Então a embalagem laminada tem sempre esse problema com o abrir!

My main concern is about this part

> Embalagens de salgadinho por exemplo, elas são laminadas.

Is that part right, or should it be:

> Embalagens de salgadinho por exemplo, elas são laminada.

without the plural on the last word "laminada". Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My answer didn't notice that, from a non-native speaker, "embalagens (plural feminine) de salgadinho (singular masculine)" could have subject agreement with either of the two parts - *são laminadas*, or *é laminado*. An answer focusing on that would be a good addition to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, the correct is using the plural: "embalagens de salgadinho são *laminadas*".

The same way that the gender must agree with the subject, so must the plural agree.

We wouldn't say "as embalagens são *laminados". We wouldn't say "a embalagem é *laminadas". We should say:

- **A** embalagem (é) laminad**a**;
- **As** embalagens (são) laminad**as**;
- **O** invólucro laminad**o**;
- **Os** invólucros laminad**os**.

If we search for other examples, it's easy to reach this conclusion by induction:

- A mãe velh**a**;
- As filhas alt**as**;
- O rei tiran**o**;
- Os patos branc**os**.

---

We **would not** write:

- A mãe velhas*;
- As filhas alta*;
- O rei tiranos*;
- Os patos branco*.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense and it clears my doubt!

Comment: It has all been said here.  +1

Comment: 7) Quando um único substantivo é modificado por dois ou mais adjetivos no singular, podem ser usadas as construções:

a) O substantivo permanece no singular e coloca-se o artigo antes do último adjetivo.

Por Exemplo:
Admiro a cultura espanhola e a portuguesa.

b) O substantivo vai para o plural e omite-se o artigo antes do adjetivo.

Por Exemplo:
Admiro as culturas espanhola e portuguesa. (http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint59.php)

Comment: @AndréLyra podes abrir uma resposta mais complexa e completa, que inclua essas exceções :) - o caso 7 e o caso 2, pelo menos.

Comment: Yes! This touches more deeply the area that I was getting confused around. For instance: "Embalagens de salgadinho... elas são laminadas." In this case we say "Embalagens de salgadinho" and not "Embalagens de salgadinhos", and that is why I was in doubt if I should use "laminadas" or "laminada". I chose that as the best answer but the technicality of the issues was better addressed in your reply because most of the samples and reasoning that ANeves mentioned, I already knew. @André Lyra, or anyone, please free to post an answer elaborating what you have described, in English if possible.

Comment: Meu comentário é para melhorar esta resposta, e indicar que a dúvida não é simplesmente sobre plurais, mas sobre concordância nominal. Ele quer entender quando não usar o plural, mesmo tendo perguntado o contrário.